# How can I play Mikeinel's "Who"?

Tags: mikeinel-who

"[Who](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rb_ZU1lCgnc&feature=related)" is a canceled video game by [Mikeinel](http://gamejolt.com/profile/mike-inel/1939/), the same guy who did the awesome [Draw With Me](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MvjZ6VkLuCM&feature=related) video.

Mikeinel also several short games, "Which", "Why", "Where", and "How".

**Question :** Is there any way to play "Who" ? Perhaps as an Easter Egg inside one of his short games?

---

Screenshot from "Who", the canceled game in question

[image: Who]

MikeInel's other, slightly creepy, short games, "Which", "Why", "Where", "How"

[image: Which]
[image: Why]
[image: Where]
[image: How]

Still from MikeInel's "Draw With Me", the theme featured in "Who"

[image: Draw With Me]

Comment: From our [FAQ](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/faq): "Speculation of the future of the industry and of upcoming release." Because of this I am voting to close your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This thread](http://forum.thegamecreators.com/?m=forum_view&b=5&t=165155&p=1) (specifically, the first post by Mike Inel himself on the second page) suggests that there may be hope for you to play Who sometime in the distant future.

> Development-wise, "Who" became too hard to work on. It's not entirely cancelled, i'm just delaying it... A lot... (I'm not sure when to continue, lol)

However, he has not as of yet released it in any shape or form, neither as a demo nor as an easter egg inside any of his other games.